# kd-tree iterative non-stack based insertion

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, graph-algorithm, knn

Im looking for iterative non-stack based (due to memory constraints, and minimal refactoring) kd-tree insertion only.

I have an entire kd-tree library working in C, functions (insert ,read, update, delete, knn search, rebalancing) I started to replace all recursive functions with iterative ones.

However, I noticed that my insertion was not working for some test data. Meaning actually the search could not find the inserted nodes when using iterative implementation but all data was found when using recursive implementation, **, therefore, the bug is in iterative insert version.**

**node structure:**

```
typedef struct kd_tree_node
{  
    struct kd_tree_node* left; 
    struct kd_tree_node* right; 
    struct kd_tree_node* parent; 
    float* dataset;  
    float distance_to_neighbor;
} kd_tree_node;
```

**Below is an iterative insertion** (i included parts directly related. No rebalacing logic, etc...):

```
void
kd_tree_add_record(kd_tree_node* root, const float data [], int depth,
        const int k_dimensions,
        const int copying, const float rebuild_threshold) {

   /*rebalancing logic is NOT relevant, which  I have NOT include, we can just build inefficient tree*/
    
    /* is root empty? */
    if (is_empty_node(root, k_dimensions)) {
        root = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);
        /*was the root set before*/
        if (is_empty_node(kd_tree_get_root(), k_dimensions)) {
            kd_tree_set_root(root);
        }
    } else {
        /*iteratively insert new node*/
        current = kd_tree_get_root();
        /*while current is NOT null*/
        while (!is_empty_node(current, k_dimensions)) {
            parent = current;
            /* Calculate current dimension (cd) of comparison */
            cd = depth % k_dimensions;
            /*determine current dimension/*/
            /*by using modula operator we can cycle through all dimensions */
            /* and decide the left or right subtree*/
            median = kd_tree_get_column_median(cd);
            //printf("kd_tree_add_record.(), median=%f\n",median);
            if (data[cd] < median) {
              current = current->left; 
               
            } else {
                current = current->right;
                
            }
            depth++;
        }//end while
        
        /*should be inserted left or right of the parent*/
        int insert_left = 1; 
        depth = 0;  
        if (!is_empty_node(parent,k_dimensions)) {
            int c = 0;
            for (; c < k_dimensions; c++) {
            
            cd = depth % k_dimensions;
            median = kd_tree_get_column_median(cd);
                if (parent->dataset[cd] < median) {
                   
                } else {
                     insert_left = 0;
                     break; 
                   
                }
            depth++;
            }
            
            if (insert_left)
            {
                 parent->left = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);
                 
            }
            else
            {
                 parent->right = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);
                 
            }
        }
        
    }//end else

}
```

**I based my iterative kd-tree insert above code, by attempting to follow the iterative binary tree insert C++ code from:** (https://www.techiedelight.com/insertion-in-bst/) which can be tested online, see below(note this not my code and its provided as reference):

```
void insertIterative(Node*& root, int key)
{
    // start with root node
    Node *curr = root;

    // pointer to store parent node of current node
    Node *parent = nullptr;

    // if tree is empty, create a new node and set root
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = newNode(key);
        return;
    }

    // traverse the tree and find parent node of key
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        // update parent node as current node
        parent = curr;

        // if given key is less than the current node, go to left subtree
        // else go to right subtree
        if (key < curr->data)
            curr = curr->left;
        else
            curr = curr->right;
    }

    // construct a new node and assign to appropriate parent pointer
    if (key < parent->data)
        parent->left = newNode(key);
    else
        parent->right = newNode(key);
}
```

**Here is my previous kd-tree recursive insertion version, which works:**

```
   kd_tree_node *
  kd_tree_add_record(kd_tree_node * root,
    const float data[], int depth,
      const int k_dimensions,
        const int copying,
          const float rebuild_threshold) {
    float median = 0.0;
    /* Tree is empty? */
    if (NULL == root || NULL == root -> dataset || is_empty_node(root, k_dimensions)) {

      root = kd_tree_new_node(data, k_dimensions, copying);

      //update the root globally
      if (kd_tree_get_root() == NULL) {
        kd_tree_set_root(root);
      }

    } else {

      /* Calculate current dimension (cd) of comparison */
      size_t cd = depth % k_dimensions;
      /*determine current dimension/*/
      /*by using modula operator we can cycle through all dimensions */

      /* and decide the left or right subtree*/
      median = kd_tree_get_column_median(cd);

      if (data[cd] < median) {

        root -> left = kd_tree_add_record(root -> left, data, depth + 1,
          k_dimensions,
          copying, rebuild_threshold);
      } else {

        root -> right = kd_tree_add_record(root -> right, data, depth + 1,
          k_dimensions,
          copying, rebuild_threshold);
      }
    } //end else
    return root;

  }
```

**current test results:**

```
-53.148998,0.000000,9.000000 Found
 7.999700,0.069812,8.000000 Found
 7.998780,0.139619,8.000000 Found
 7.997260,0.209416,8.000000 Not Found!
7.995130,0.279196,8.000000 Not Found!
 7.992390,0.348955,8.000000 Not Found!
8.987670,0.471024,9.000000 Found
8.983210,0.549437,9.000000 Found
 7.980510,0.558052,8.000000 Not Found!
 3.000000,3.000000,3.000000 Found
4.000000,4.000000,4.000000 Found
5.000000,5.000000,5.000000 Found!
100.000000,100.000000,100.000000 Found
```

**How can I extend the iterative non-stack binary insert algorithm to kd-trees?**

Really appreciated!

Comment: @wildplasser, that portion is not my code. If you read carefully, thats the binary tree code that im attempting to use a guide in order implement iterative kd-tree insert. My kd-tree is valid C, with all compiler flags on, and generates zero warnings.

Comment: I'm sorry. A solution would be to use a pointer to pointer ais the root function argument, instead of the `&*`, just as you would do with ordinary trees or lists.

Comment: Also, you'll need to get rid of the globals.

Comment: @wildplasser, did you read my reply carefully? That C++ is a code that i use as reference only, inorder implement my own code in C. The C++ NOT in my code base, it NOT in my program, i provided the link and code as reference. The problem is the function titled kd_treee_add_record(). Thanks

Comment: YES I read it carefully, probablly more carefully than you. And the solutiion is: use pointers-to pointer, it is trivial. BTW: you dind not include the definition for your stucture in your sample.

Comment: @wildplasser , do you mean use pointer to pointer in  kd_treee_add_record(kd_tree_node*  node) and convert it to kd_treee_add_record(kd_tree_node**  node)? If so, can you please explain how this change the algorithm & resolves the bug? Really appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219843/discussion-between-cyber101-and-wildplasser).